# questions about viewport overlays

Tags: 3d-view

[image: Capture]

I didn't check center but it's showing me face's center
Is this supposed to be... or?

Comment: it looks like you see the face center if you enable Edges and choose face select mode, not sure why though

Comment: Hello :). Blender only shows face center when in *Face select* mode. Switch to edge/vertex select mode and it'll disappear. It has nothing to do with overlays.